# How does a machine choose between two different GPUs?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I currently have two NVidia GPUs in my machine, a GTX970 and a GTX650.

Obviously, the disparity prevents SLI. How does my machine choose which GPU will render for a given piece of software? Does the GPU driver try to choose the best of the two? Does the OS choose a default device (that I can change)? Or is it just up to the particular piece of software to intelligently ask for the right device?

I have two cards because I do a lot of 3D rendering, and in *that* case, the software uses both of them explicitly on separate threads, without SLI. How is this decision made in the case of more conventional pieces of software?

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Does that mean that it also does the rendering on that GPU, or could it be rendering on one and piping it to display on the other one?

Comment: Turned my comments in to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For displaying to screen it uses the GPU you plugged your monitor in to.

For the 3D rendering it is using special extensions called CUDA (for Nividia cards specifically) or OpenCL (A wrapper for CUDA and other interfaces) that let it use the GPU's power to do the rendering, so that is why your rendering software can use both cards.

The only time a image is rendered on one card and piped to the other is when you are using a SLI configuration and part of the image is rendered with one card and part of the image is rendered with the other.

Comment: So, to be clear, I should see a performance change if I plug my monitor into one GPU versus the other (so long as I have no SLI), right?

Comment: In theory, yes. You would need to benchmark and test.

Comment: Cool! That's not quite what I expected to learn, I'll have to check that out!

Comment: Your last paragraph is not entirely accurate. Switchable graphics, (e.g. Nvidia Optimus) also involves rending an image on one card and piping it over to the other, specifically, the display outputs are only connected to the IGP, so anything rendered on the discrete GPU must be copied over to the IGP's frame buffer for viewing.